# A friendly jigsaw

Tags: cipher, visual, jigsaw-puzzle

This puzzle belongs to the puzzle series: [hyper-modern art](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=hyper-modern%20is%3Aquestion)

---

The two friends in the gallery of hyper-modern art move into a room which is painted completely in black and white.  Strange, wavy lines cover the floor and seem to 'flow' together in the central painting, the only one in the room.

*"Quite dull, I dare say. If you don't mind, I'll just move on to the next room."*

"Wait a bit. I think you would be well advised to take a closer look at the painting. It is called `friendly advice` after all."

*"Bah! I've lost my HUD and looking at all these lines makes me dizzy. I move on!"*

The man turns around and towards the only other door leading out of this room. A security camera is observing it, but he ignores. The moment he touches the handle, he gets a mild, but still hurting electric shock and some alarm bell tweezes.

*"Jesus! What's that supposed to mean?!"*

"I told you," the other friend says with a broad grin, "One always has to look for hidden meanings in the gallery of hyper-modern art."

With that, he passes his confused friend, ignores his attempt to warn him, and grabs the door handle, opens the door, and walks on to the next room.

"Are you coming, or what?" he beams back at his friend.

*"Sure."*

But the moment he touches the handle, he is shocked again.

*"WTF!"* he shouts out, holding his aching hand.

"I guess you need to find your passcode first, my friend. Have fun, I'll wait next door".

---

[image: Jigsaw]

---

> The goal of this puzzle is to derive the one thing the one man knew and his friend didn't. The one thing which let him pass the door unharmed.

Comment: A person can only pass the door at second try. Not serious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He has to

> Smile

1st level

> [image]

2nd level

> [image]

3rd level

> [image]

Comment: Sell done. Btw: *the other friend says with a broad grin*  and *he beams back* were two hints, too.

Answer (score 5):

Aww, looks like I'm late

Nevertheless, here's what I've done

Step 1

> [image: please ignore bad cropping in top left corner] please ignore bad cropping in top left corner

Step 2

> [image: Step 2]

Step 3

> [image: Step 3]

Final answer

> Smile!

Comment: @BmyGuest I sure did! This is my first time here and I looked at all of your puzzles, which are awesome :) also, I'm getting a Holmes and Watson vibe from the two friends